# rewrite javascript containing closure in typescript class

Tags: typescript

how to rewrite below javascript in typescript class.
The greet2 function in prototype is an immediately invoke function.

```
function Greeter(greeting) {
    this.greeting = greeting;
}

Greeter.prototype.greet = function() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
}

//an immediately invoke function
Greeter.prototype.greet2 = function{
    let blabla = 'hello, ';
    return function greet2(foo) {
        return blabla + foo;
    }
}();

let greeter = new Greeter({message: "world"});  

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet2('tom'));
};

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the property and then initialize it on the prototype:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
    greet2!: (foo) => string;  // in case of strictPropertyInitialization
    static staticInitializer() {
        // Here we have access to non-public members of `Greeter`.
        Greeter.prototype.greet2 = function(){
            let blabla = 'hello, ';
            return function greet2(this: Greeter, foo) {
                return blabla + foo;
            }
        }();
    }
}
Greeter.staticInitializer();
```

When [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26254) is implemented, you'll be able to use a real static initializer.

Answer (score 0):

> how to rewrite below javascript in typescript class

Using a property initializer:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
    greet2 = (() => {                      // HERE 
        let blabla = 'hello, ';
        return function greet2(foo) {
            return blabla + foo;
        }
    })()
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function () {
    alert(greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: This is less efficient than the original: it's evaluated once for each object instantiated instead of once when the class is defined.